# Chrome show green lines on Mac OS X BigSur

Tags: macos, google-chrome, macos-bigsur

I have no idea why lately, I experience these green lines

I'm on:

- Google Chrome is up to date Version `90.0.4430.212` (Official Build) (x86_64)
- Mac OS X `11.2.3 (20D91)`

Sample site
[image]

Inspect Element
[image]

YouTube
[image]

Does anyone else face this too?

***How do we fix this?***

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a graphic cards issue, if you disable Hardware Acceleration on your browser, it should go away.

```
chrome://settings/?search=hardware
edge://settings/?search=hardware
```

Turn off Hardware Acceleration and restart the browser. It should go away.